# How to call a function after the Morris Donut chart draw event

Tags: javascript, html, morris.js, donut-chart

Is there a way to call a function after the Morris Donut chart draw event. I need to add a class to the parent div after the chart has been drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify the file morris.js, at the end of the function `Donut.prototype.redraw`. You can try to add this on line 1936 (just before `return _results;`). `if (typeof my_callback === 'function') {` will check if the function exists, so that you can use this modified version of morris.js also in pages that have not this callback.

```
if (typeof my_callback === 'function') { 
    my_callback()
}
```